# show results of last six months

Tags: php, sql, date

I'd like to show the results of a sql query of the last six months, and to show the month and year of the results, the code i'll show isn't complete because in fact it's much longer but i've tried to give the most important parts.. 
I used this function that returns the query ( the parameter `$k` is the interval...):

---

i have a loop that increments $k so that i can make the query for the six months:

```
for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){
        $requete = query($i);
        SQL_QUERY($requete); // the function that executes the query
    }
```

---

I can get the results of the last months untill january but not december because the year is 2012 not 2013.

---

I'VE tried to make this so that the year will be current year -1 when the month is 12:

```
function print_date($y_m){
        foreach($y_m as $row){
             echo $row[0];
        if ($row[0] == 12){
             $_SESSION["y"]= $_SESSION["y"]+1;
             echo $_SESSION["y"];
        }
}
```

but it's not working, :/ does someone have an idea how to be able to do that ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get data for last six month with simple SQL query like this:

```
SELECT SRC as SOURCE FROM mytable
WHERE TYPE = 'SMS' 
    AND date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 month)
```

#### Extends

If you nedd one month you may modify query:

```
SELECT SRC as SOURCE FROM mytable
WHERE TYPE = 'SMS' 
    AND YEAR(date) = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $k month)
    AND MONTH(date) = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $k month)
```

Comment: No that not what I want, because i was to get different tables, each table corresponds to a one month results.

Comment: This would indeed return all the data for the last 6 months, however the OP *may* have been using one query per month for a reason.

Comment: @Kirk ERW In that case, I suggest you edit your question as you have left information that is critical to your answer.

Comment: If nee aonly one month, add this condition "AND date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 month)"